# Angular js :set method in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have `self.model.set('pristineMethod', utils.cloneDeep(self.model.get()));`

example

```
var SearchModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    performSearch: function(str) {
        //assign to local variable, so that it is accesible in callback's closure
        var self = this; 
        $.get('/' + str, function(results) {
            // are you sure it should be data?
            console.log(data);
            self.set("results", data);
        });
    },
});
```

I have to do this concept in angular js object.

Comment: Needs a bit more detail - not clear what your problem is!

Comment: @DuncanThacker I have updated the description

Answer (score 0):

if you set value like

```
self.model.set('pristineMethod', { pristineMethod : utils.cloneDeep(self.model.get())} );
```

so "pristineMethod" is in object